# Correcting file name before creation of file - Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

The file creation on Linux fails if the file name is corrupted, I mean if the file name contains ?? due to encoding issues or whatever. Is there any function which can correct the file name by removing characters which can cause the file creation to fail.

*Edit*:
Here is the file name

Rumeurs (Théâtre - Poiret - Mondy - Darlan - Nadeau).mp4

Now on Ubuntu French it looks like

Rumeurs (Th??tre - Poiret - Mondy - Darlan - Nadeau).mp4

and file creation fails

Comment: Where are you getting the filename from? User input?

Comment: @merlin2011 Internet, actually when downloading files

Comment: The only illegal chars in filenames on Linux are slash and null byte. Everything else is ok. Please describe your problem with more details, file creation should not fail because of that.

Comment: Here http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+3.+Input+Validation/3.7+Validating+Filenames+and+Paths/
And
Here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3001/Validating-file-names

Comment: There is no "Correction mechanism", but I have just tried and I can create files with those file names. What does the errorString() method of QFile says after the write if it fails?

Comment: @LaszloPapp the ?? above are different, this is the displayed file name. I can give more details later.

Comment: Yeah, please do because I cannot reproduce it. Can you create files with those names using core utils or busybox from command line, i.e. not Qt?

Comment: Are you writing that utf-8 filename into your editor, or it is obtained in the "background"? If it is typed in some file, I would say it is better to check the editor settings.